# Calling Instance method. Error in array message

Tags: ruby, object, oop, error-handling

I am new to ruby. I am trying to call my instance method (shake) in order for it to return the string "cling" but it keeps giving me the message : undefined method `break' for [50]:Array (NoMethodError).   Any help in understanding why, please?

```
class PiggyBank
  def initialize
    @storage = []
  end

  def insert(coin)
    @storage << coin
  end

  def shake
    if @storage.empty?
      nil
    else
      'clink'
    end
  end

  def break
    @storage.count
  end
end

p PiggyBank.new.insert(50).break
```

Comment: I understand my code is calling the method .break but I have tried it with .shake. Sorry, I posted the wrong return

Comment: your `insert` method returns an array. you're trying to call `shake` on an array, rather than an instance of PiggyBank.

Comment: Also, you should avoid naming a method "break", as this is a reserved keyword in Ruby.

Comment: I suggest you write `pb = PiggyBank.new; pb.insert(50); pb.count`. I've changed `break` to `count` to avoid confusion with the keyword `break`. Ruby has several built-in methods `count` but a method `PiggyBank#count` should cause no confusion (and is more descriptive than `break`). Chaining two unrelated operations is a hack.

Comment: In general, if you keep getting the same error message without changing the code you just need to be patient. Eventually, the code will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert method returns an array which has no method called break (break is a method you defined on PiggyBank).

You can either return an instance of PiggyBank from your insert method (that way you can chain additional instance methods such as break) or structure the code differently.

```
def insert(coin)
   @storage << coin
   self
end
```

Comment: `tap { @storage << coin }` if you wanna be fancy about it